# json calling other json using php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need your help..I would like to call a json value using a json value...

here's my sample json...

**first json:**

```
{
  "first_name": "Richard Catibog",
  "last_name": "",
  "display_name": "Richard Catibog ",
  "roles": {
    "owner": false,
    "administrator": true
  },
  "login_count": 108,
  "enabled": true,
  "departments": [
    1817719575,
    1817719887,
    1817722991
  ],
  "id": 4142095,
  "last_login": "2017-07-12T10:03:57Z",
  "create_date": "2017-04-28T12:09:57Z",
  "email": "richard.catibog+21757948948@51talk.com"
},
{
  "first_name": "Rovi Cruz",
  "last_name": "",
  "display_name": "Rovi Roy Cruz ",
  "roles": {
    "owner": false,
    "administrator": true
  },
  "login_count": 98,
  "enabled": true,
  "departments": [
    1817719575,
    1817719887,
    1817722991
  ],
  "id": 4225009,
  "last_login": "2017-07-13T00:37:27Z",
  "create_date": "2017-06-05T06:15:49Z",
  "email": "rovi.cruz+21821290968@51talk.com"
}
```

Second json:

```
[
  {
    "description": "Fees Support for American Academy",
    "settings": {

    },
    "enabled": false,
    "id": 1817719575,
    "name": "AA Fees Support [L2]"
  },
  {
    "description": "American Academy",
    "settings": {

    },
    "enabled": true,
    "id": 1817722991,
    "name": "Lesson and Fee Support"
  },
  {
    "description": "Technical Support",
    "settings": {

    },
    "enabled": true,
    "id": 1817719887,
    "name": "Technical Support"
  }
]
```

I would like to call the id on the second and echo the names using the departments id list on first json...

here's what i get...
[image]
but the result that i want to see is AA Fees Support [L2], Lesson and Fee Support and Technical Support...

thank you, hope you can help me...

Comment: Would you like to provide and example result so we can see exactly what you mean

Comment: @RiggsFolly done editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this I made an array `$desc` that is keyed on the departments id numbers so you can easily convert the id to a Descrition

```
$js1 = '{
        "first_name": "Richard Catibog", "last_name": "",
        "display_name": "Richard Catibog ",
        "roles": { "owner": false,"administrator": true},
        "login_count": 108,"enabled": true,
        "departments": [1817719575,1817719887,1817722991],
        "id": 4142095,"last_login": "2017-07-12T10:03:57Z",
        "create_date": "2017-04-28T12:09:57Z",
        "email": "richard.catibog+21757948948@51talk.com"
}';

$js2 = '[
  {
    "description": "Fees Support for American Academy",
    "settings": {},"enabled": false,"id": 1817719575,
    "name": "AA Fees Support [L2]"
  },
  {
    "description": "American Academy",
    "settings": {},"enabled": true,"id": 1817722991,
    "name": "Lesson and Fee Support"
  },
  {
    "description": "Technical Support",
    "settings": {},"enabled": true,"id": 1817719887,
    "name": "Technical Support"
  }
]';

$first = json_decode($js1);
//print_r($first);
$second = json_decode($js2);
//print_r($second);

// make array key'd on the id
$desc = [];
foreach ($second as $s) {
    $desc[$s->id] = $s;
}
print_r($desc);

// go through all the dept id's in the first array
// getting a matching desctipyion from array 2
foreach ( $first->departments as $dept) {
    echo $desc[$dept]->description . PHP_EOL;
}
```

**UPDATE:** After the first json data structure got changed to an array of objects

> NOTE I changed your first json data structure to make it valid JSON by adding `[]` around the 2 objects to make a valid JSON data structure i.e. an array of objects.

All you need to do in this case is add a loop to lop over the now array of objects.

```
$js1 = '[{
  "first_name": "Richard Catibog",
  "last_name": "",
  "display_name": "Richard Catibog ",
  "roles": {    "owner": false,    "administrator": true  },
  "login_count": 108,
  "enabled": true,
  "departments": [    1817719575,    1817719887,    1817722991  ],
  "id": 4142095,
  "last_login": "2017-07-12T10:03:57Z",
  "create_date": "2017-04-28T12:09:57Z",
  "email": "richard.catibog+21757948948@51talk.com"
},
{
  "first_name": "Rovi Cruz",
  "last_name": "",
  "display_name": "Rovi Roy Cruz ",
  "roles": {    "owner": false,    "administrator": true  },
  "login_count": 98,
  "enabled": true,
  "departments": [    1817719575,    1817719887,    1817722991  ],
  "id": 4225009,
  "last_login": "2017-07-13T00:37:27Z",
  "create_date": "2017-06-05T06:15:49Z",
  "email": "rovi.cruz+21821290968@51talk.com"
}]';

$js2 = '[
  {
    "description": "Fees Support for American Academy",
    "settings": {},"enabled": false,"id": 1817719575,
    "name": "AA Fees Support [L2]"
  },
  {
    "description": "American Academy",
    "settings": {},"enabled": true,"id": 1817722991,
    "name": "Lesson and Fee Support"
  },
  {
    "description": "Technical Support",
    "settings": {},"enabled": true,"id": 1817719887,
    "name": "Technical Support"
  }
]';

$first = json_decode($js1);
//print_r($first);
$second = json_decode($js2);
//print_r($second);

// make array key'd on the id
$desc = [];
foreach ($second as $s) {
    $desc[$s->id] = $s;
}
//print_r($desc);

//Loop through all the first array of object
foreach ( $first as $f) {
    // go through all the dept id's in the first array
    // getting a matching desctipyion from array 2
    foreach ( $f->departments as $dept) {
        echo $desc[$dept]->description . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

```
Fees Support for American Academy
Technical Support
American Academy

Fees Support for American Academy
Technical Support
American Academy
```

Comment: also an error `Trying to get property of non-object in `

Comment: Must be something in the implementation, it runs here just fine

Comment: Note I do not  json_decode using the convert to array option. Its a perfectly good object so I left it that way

Comment: Thank Man... this is great... I made some adjustment, but this is really helpful.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

here you go

```
$json1 = '{
        "first_name": "Richard Catibog",
        "last_name": "",
        "display_name": "Richard Catibog ",
        "roles": {
          "owner": false,
          "administrator": true
        },
        "login_count": 108,
        "enabled": true,
        "departments": [
          1817719575,
          1817719887,
          1817722991
        ],
        "id": 4142095,
        "last_login": "2017-07-12T10:03:57Z",
        "create_date": "2017-04-28T12:09:57Z",
        "email": "richard.catibog+21757948948@51talk.com"
}
';
$json2 ='[
  {
    "description": "Fees Support for American Academy",
    "settings": {

    },
    "enabled": false,
    "id": 1817719575,
    "name": "AA Fees Support [L2]"
  },
  {
    "description": "American Academy",
    "settings": {

    },
    "enabled": true,
    "id": 1817722991,
    "name": "Lesson and Fee Support"
  },
  {
    "description": "Technical Support",
    "settings": {

    },
    "enabled": true,
    "id": 1817719887,
    "name": "Technical Support"
  }
]';

$json1 = json_decode($json1, true);
$json2 = json_decode($json2, true);

$department = function($id) use($json2) {
    foreach($json2 as $dep) {
        if($dep["id"] == $id) {
            return $dep;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

foreach($json1["departments"] as $id) {
    $dep = $department($id);
    if(is_array($dep)) {
        echo sprintf("id: %s, name: %s\n", $id, $dep["name"]);
    }

}
```

Comment: im guessing your first json is an array of objects and not just an object as you stated in you question? put another foreach loop around the first, and loop through json1's elements.